# memoir: subcaptions outside float

Tags: memoir, subcaption, outofloats

For figures outside of caption memoir define for example

```
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}
```

Is there a way to similarly define fixed subcaption? That it can be used in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{CC}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-a}\newline
(a)%\figsubcaption{sub caption a}
    &
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-b}\newline
(b)%\figsubcaption{sub caption b}
    \end{tabularx}
\figcaption{figure caption}
\end{center}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's similar, but you need to let `memoir` know that you are going to have a subfloat, thus `\subcaption` and not `\caption` has to be used; this can be done using the optional argument for `\newfixedcaption`:

```
\newfixedcaption[\subcaption]{\subfigcaption}{figure}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}
\newfixedcaption[\subcaption]{\subfigcaption}{figure}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{CC}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-a}\newline
  \subfigcaption{sub caption a}
    &
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-b}\newline
  \subfigcaption{sub caption b}
  \end{tabularx}
  \figcaption{figure caption}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzales Medina, perfect. In my search for solution and experiments I was close to this, but not enough :-). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gonzales Medina, its a pity, that this case hoe to defini fix sub captions  is not mentioned in memoir manual `memman`. I hop that in some new version summary of your answer will be added to it.

Comment: @Zarko You're right. Since the current maintainer of `memoir` is a regular here,  I can easily propose this to him.

Comment: @@Gonzales Medina,new problem: in real case I also use `subfig` package with option `caption=false`. If I put it after `\subfigcaption` definition, then this definition work properly, but subfloats not ... and vice versa. I will try to compose a new question, but before I need confirm my observation

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I can confirm your observation. Notice, however, that `memoir` provides native methods to handle subfigures and subtables, so I wouldn't see the need to use `subfig` with `memoir`. If you *really* need `subfig` with `memoir`, the best thing to do would be to open a fresh question.

Comment: Is there a solution for book class too? Should I post a new question?