# memoir: subcaption outside float, cross referencing problems

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, subcaption, outofloats

On my question ["memoir: subcaption outside float"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253684/memoir-subcaptions-outside-float) Gonzales Medina provide the answer, which in first hand solve my basic problem but on second hand open two new:

- subcaptions can not be referenced. It seems that their definition should be upgraded with referencing ability.
- It clash with `subfloats` determined with `subfig` package, which I use (up to now) for sub floats.

Later problem I partly solve with use `\subbotom` of memoir package instead of `subfloat` of subfig package. Instead `usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` I put in preamble `\let\subfloat\subbottom` by which I (try to) preserve the syntax for sub floats constructs in my old documents:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%%--------------------------------------------------------------%
    \newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}
    \newfixedcaption{\tabcaption}{table}
\newsubfloat{figure}
    \newfixedcaption[\subcaption]{\subfigcaption}{figure}
%%--------------------------------------------------------------%
    \let\subfloat\subbottom
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[sub figure  left \label{subfig-1}]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\hsize]{example-image-a}}
\subfloat[sub figure right \label{subfig-2}]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\hsize]{example-image-b}}
\caption{test}
    \end{figure}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{CC}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-a}\newline
\subfigcaption{sub caption a} \label{subfig-3}
    &
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-b}\newline
\subfigcaption{sub caption b}  \label{subfig-4}
    \end{tabularx}
\figcaption{figure caption}\label{fig:3-4}
\end{center}

Added test of referencing: see Fig. \ref{subfig-1}, Fig. \ref{subfig-2} and Fig. \ref{fig:3-4}, which is consist of Fig. \ref{subfig-3} and Fig. \ref{subfig-4}..
    \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

*Questions:*

- how to `subfigcaption` add referencing ability?
- how to redefine style of references mark from `0.1(a)` to `0.1a`?

Comment: `\subfigcaption{...\label{...}}` works.

Comment: @daleif, indeed. With this my firs (sub) question is answered.  I wonder, why this is not necessary to do at `figcaption`?

Comment: You are not using `\figcaption` in your example. If added you will notice that `\figcaption{}\label{}` does not catch the correct number (because the number stuff inside `\figcaption` is made inside a group

Comment: @daleif,  I edit my MWE to show the working of `\figcaption`. Up to now I didn't observe the problem you mentioned. Now is more important, how to change the style of referencing mark (my second question)

Comment: @daleif I think you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question (1) just place `\label` inside `\subfigcaption{...}`. This is due to how `\subfigcaption` is made. The material for `\label` is made inside a group and thus not available in `\subfigcaption{}\label{}`

As for (2), I don't think it is possible to easily be changed. Especially if we want (2) in text, and 1a at not 1(a). The code is hardwired into the construction. I'll add it to my `memoir` todo list (actually it is already there, I'll just up the priority)

Comment: well, this means that I should wait for while :-). This is ok. Meanwhile I will avoid to use `subficaption` as well `subbottom` out of the floats as I do so far. Thank you!